# Apollo useQuery gives null result for the subscription in react app

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using Apollo Client (React) 3.0. The backend is sending the subscriptions correctly.

I am getting a null value for the result "prev" when I receive 2 subscriptions (received and sent) at the same time from the backend.

My use case here is auto-reply on certain keywords. For eg:

**Received**: Help ( sub: MESSAGE_RECEIVED_SUBSCRIPTION )

**Sent**: "Auto-response" (sub: MESSAGE_SENT_SUBSCRIPTION )

In this case, "prev" is set on received subscription but not on sent subscription.

Here is my code:

```
const { loading, error, data, subscribeToMore } = useQuery<any>(GET_CONVERSATION_QUERY, {
    variables: queryVariables,
  });

  // handle subscription for message received and sent
  const getMessageResponse = useCallback(() => {
    // message received subscription
    subscribeToMore({
      document: MESSAGE_RECEIVED_SUBSCRIPTION,
      variables: queryVariables,
      updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
        console.log('calling message received sub');
        ...
      },
    });

    // message sent subscription
    subscribeToMore({
      document: MESSAGE_SENT_SUBSCRIPTION,
      variables: queryVariables,
      updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
        console.log('calling message sent sub');
        ...
      },
    });
  }, [subscribeToMore, queryVariables, updateConversations]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getMessageResponse();
    // we should call useEffect only once hence []
  }, []);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue. There were differences in the returned values for query and subscription hence, it was failing and maybe triggering the query again resulting in the null result on the second run.

Hope this helps!